# jar package is not behaving as expected

Tags: spring-boot, itext, thymeleaf

I have made a code using spring boot and itextpdf 5, actually I am trying to do something like this example

```
https://github.com/aboullaite/SpringBoot-Excel-Csv
```

my code is working fine when I run it in my STS IDE, but it shows error as error resolving template when I create jar file and run it, can anyone please help

Edit:- I am using thymeleaf for html view

## Code

this is my webconfig class

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer
            .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .favorPathExtension(true).ignoreAcceptHeader(true);
}
@Bean
public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(ContentNegotiationManager manager) {
    ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
    resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);

    // Define all possible view resolvers
    List<ViewResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<>();

    resolvers.add(csvViewResolver());
    resolvers.add(excelViewResolver());
    resolvers.add(pdfViewResolver());
   
    resolver.setViewResolvers(resolvers);
    return resolver;
}



/*
 * Configure View resolver to provide XLS output using Apache POI library to
 * generate XLS output for an object content
 */
@Bean
public ViewResolver excelViewResolver() {
    return new ExcelViewResolver();
}

/*
 * Configure View resolver to provide Csv output using Super Csv library to
 * generate Csv output for an object content
 */
@Bean
public ViewResolver csvViewResolver() {
    return new CsvViewResolver();
}

/*
 * Configure View resolver to provide Pdf output using iText library to
 * generate pdf output for an object content
 */
@Bean
public ViewResolver pdfViewResolver() {
    return new PdfViewResolver();
}
```

}

and here are my controller methods

```
@GetMapping( "/download")
public String download(Model model) {

model.addAttribute("cards", new StudentsDto());
return "getReportCard";
```

}

```
@PostMapping("/download")
public String postReportCard(@ModelAttribute("cards") StudentsDto cards, Model model){

List<Students> sList=studentService.searchByClassSectionBySession(cards.getClassSection(), cards.getSession());
model.addAttribute("studentsList", sList);

  return "";
}
```

My question is , If everythinbg is working fine on running code as spring boot application through my STS IDE then why the jar I have created is not showing pdf views ?
I have created jars from my sts ide, i did maven clean and then i created jar using maven install

## Solved

Was a stupid mistake, I don't kn how but in my template folder I changed the name of file getReportCard.html as getReportCArd.html.

Was a silly mistake and I checked upon each and every possible configuration. :-)

Comment: Hey! My car ist not starting. Can you help? -> Could you? No. Give us please more information. Error messages, configuration, pieces of code...

Comment: Hey @Ph03n1x, are you sure it isn't related to the alternator?

Comment: @AsierAranbarri Nah, I was turning the key in the wrong direction and that's why it didn't start...

Comment: Please check the link I had posted, I have made similar code, which is running fine when i run it as spring boot applicatin from my STS IDE, but when i create jar file and run it using java -jar myjar.jar command it shows an error for pdf view as error resaolving template

Comment: @Ph03n1x I was so close, hope I was helpful mate! +1 on your well defined question

Comment: @Gaurav At least post the error you see in the jar...

Comment: jar is not showing any error, its just not showing the pdf view and showing and error page as could not resolve template. but same piece of code was showing pdf view when i was running it in STS, that is so confusing as rest of the html pages are showing fine with jar

Comment: Did you create a fat-jar with all the dependencies and resources? I.e. do you have maven build configured to create a jar with all the dependencies, resources and libs?

Comment: yes I created the fat jar

Comment: Finally solved it, was a stupid mistake, please check the update in this question